# How are the lower and upper bound values of the moths determined in the Moth-Flame Optimization algorithm?

Tags: optimization, papers, meta-heuristics, moth-flame-optimization

I am currently implementing the Moth-Flame Optimization (MFO) Algorithm, based on the paper: [Moth-Flame Optimization Algorithm: A Novel Nature-inspired Heuristic Paradigm](https://fardapaper.ir/mohavaha/uploads/2020/03/Fardapaper-Moth-flame-optimization-algorithm-A-novel-nature-inspired-heuristic-paradigm.pdf).

To calculate the values of the Moths, it uses two arrays of values, which contain upper and lower values for each variable. However, as far as I can see. it mentions nothing about what these values are. Quoting from the paper:

> As can be seen, there are two other arrays called $ub$ and $lb$. These matrixes define the upper and lower bounds of the variables as follows:
>
> $ub = [ub_1, ub_2, ub_3, \dots,ub_{n-1}, ub_n]$
>
> where $ub_i$ indicates the upper bound of the $i$-th variable.
>
> $lb = [lb_1, lb_2, lb_3, \dots, ub_{n-1}, ub_n]$
>
> where $lb_i$ indicates the lower bound of the $i$-th variable

After that, it says nothing more about this matter

So, if anyone has any idea of how these bound values are determined, please tell me!

Comment: I didn't read the paper and I don't have time to read it to help you more now, but if you don't get an answer, you should probably look at an available implementation of MFO online, for example, [this](https://github.com/thieu1995/mealpy/blob/master/mealpy/swarm_based/MFO.py) or [this](https://github.com/7ossam81/EvoloPy/blob/master/optimizers/MFO.py). I have no idea of the quality of the implementations, so I can't guarantee that they are even correct or contain the answer to your question.